# Differences between Office Interop libraries

Tags: c#, ms-word, version, office-interop

I am working on a C# .NET v4.0 application which includes generation of Word documents. The application uses the version 14.0.0.0 of the Microsoft Office Interop Word library.

My computer is running Office 2010 (Office14) and I am wondering what are the differences between the versions 14.0.0.0 and the 15.0.0.0 for the library?

Is there any obligation to use one or the other of these two libraries depending on which version of Office I am running?

Answer (score 1):

If you link your app to the version 14.0.0.0 (Word 2010), it will work with Word 2013 (version 15) if you use the "Embed Interop Types" feature in Visual Studio.

If you link to 15.0.0.0, it will not work with Word 2010.

Linking to 15.0.0.0 will let you access to new functionality of 2013 if any.

Comment: Thank you, that's interesting. So that means if I have Word 2013, I can reference either one of the two. I cannot find any good link talking about functionality differences between the two libraries. Would you have any? Thanks

Comment: What's new for Word 2013 developers: https://msdn.microsoft.com/FR-FR/library/office/ff838936.aspx

Comment: Thank you for the link. All this to say there actually is not really anything new for Word document generation..

Answer (score -1):

If you don't need any automation of the application (Word) itself then I would recommand to use the offical `Open XML SDK 2.5 for Microsoft Office` to process any `xlsx` `docx` or `pptx`.

[Download Open XML SDK](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30425)

**Update**

I think it does not matter which version. More important is that your implementation works with the version that the customer has currently installed! Maybe or maybe not there could be some breaking changes between the interop interfaces between major versions.

Comment: Second that, office automation is a major pain, only one app on the machine can do it at once, it can be a massive resource hog. The SDK is a bit quirky but way better and none of the worrying about not cleaning up all you unmanaged resources.

Comment: I cannot recode the whole thing using another library. My question is more about would there be a good reason for me to advise my client to use one or the other version of the interop word library, according to the office version he is running..? Thank you